How to make right alignment when using latex
I am trying to write my thesis in latex but am stuck with this alignment problem. I need only the heading to be written aligned not the content text, I have tried some instructions but it shows me the right alignment but the inside text is missing.
\newpage
\lhead{\input{1}}

\newpage
\lhead{\emph{Contents}} % Set the left side page header to "Contents"
\tableofcontents % Write out the Table of Contents


{\raggedleft % Right-align the heading "Abstract"
\textsc{\textbf{\fontsize{31}{32}\selectfont{List of Figures}}}\\[0.5cm] % University name
\hrule % Horizontal line
}


Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you and add a minimal working example (MWE) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}.

BTW: If \lhead is a command to change the page header, I would not recommend to use \input{…} as an argument, because usually this would need to input the file again and again for every printed page. Although the file is probably cached by the OS in this case, this can noticeably slow down document generation.

If this is a question about page [tag:header-footer], please have a look at the linked tag for relevant questions and answers and also CTAN topic page-hf for relevant packages and the corresponding manuals. If it is instead a question about [tag:sectioning] and the styles of chapter or section titles, please have a look at the also linked tag.
